# Inserting a value in a column in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am not that expert in SSIS. Can anybody help me out on my work.I want to insert 0 value

to all records in a table for column sales.current value for that column is Null

Comment: Is there an issue with just using an SQL Update query? Is it a huge number of records?

Comment: Not an expert in SSIS ... nor T-SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an update SQL statement:

```
update sales set current = 0 where column is null
```

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz: Thansk :-)